# jQuery dialog - return table to code behind method

Tags: jquery, asp.net, jquery-ui

I've a jQuery dialog box, that contains html table. When I click OK button of the dialog, I need to pass this table to a method in code behind.
Here's what I tried:

```
$("#custom-modal").dialog({
            height: 200,
            modal: true,
            buttons: { "OK": function () {
                var table1 = $("#customTable").val();
                $.ajax({
                    type: "POST",
                    url: "MyPage.aspx/BindCustom",
                    data: ({ param1: table1 }),
                    error: function (XMLHttpRequest, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                        alert(textStatus);
                    },
                    success: function (result) {
                        alert("success");
                    }
                });

                $(this).dialog("close");
                return true;
            }, "Cancel": function () {
                $(this).dialog("close");
                return false;
            }
            }

        });
```

BindCustom is webmethod on code behind. But it's not even called. Please help...

Comment: Use fiddler2 to see if the request is getting processed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

one of the issues is that you need to replace $("#customTable").val(); with $("#customTable").html(); and you can use the chrome inspector to see if there is a request going from your page to the server or not from the "Network" tab